# How to integrate Picasa with iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I want to integrate picasa web album with iPhone, but I don't know how to implement. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There is one API for accessing the web albums from picasa

http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/overview.html

The API let you send and receive albums formatted as GData feeds. After securely authenticating to Google, you can request all the albums and the photos from an album, create new albums, replace and delete photos, and also search results.

Comment: Can we use it in iOS 9