# picasa integration for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to integrate Picasa with iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675255/how-to-integrate-picasa-with-iphone)

I want to integrate picasa in my application like facebook and twitter. How to implement the code for this. Please give any suggesion which is better way for integrating picasa?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Picasa Web Albums Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/overview.html)

Quoting from that page:

> The Picasa Web Albums Data API allows for websites and programs to
>   integrate with Picasa Web Albums, enabling users to create albums,
>   upload and retrieve photos, comment on photos, and more!

Amongst other things, there are links to a [Developer's Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/2.0/developers_guide.html) and some [code samples](http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/code.html).